# NodeJS fs.writeFile fails on linux when the path has spaces

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, filesystems

I'm using the module 'fs' to perform some OS integration and one of the procedures I do is to create/write files on the system. I've noticed that when using the function 'writeFile' and the path has spaces the procedure fails.

eg (working):

```
fs.writeFile('/home/john/mypath/myfile.txt', 'blabla', function() {})
```

eg (failing):

```
fs.writeFile('/home/john/my path/myfile.txt', 'blabla', function() {})
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

> { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory']
>     errno: -2,
>     code: 'ENOENT',
>     syscall: 'open',
>     path: '"/home/john/my path/another cool/project.txt"' }

Any insights on how to workaround this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating node the problem no longer exists..

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the spaces with a backwards slash.
ie ..

fs.writeFile('/home/john/my\ path/myfile.txt', 'blabla', function() {})

Comment: I've tried that too but it automatically added another \ prior to mine, so it ends in: "aa\\ bbb".. In any case, the situation was solved after updating the environment (figures..)